# Should I vote to close discussion and feature-request questions that are about the same topic as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, meta, per-site-meta

Let’s say I have 2 questions with exactly the same topic, asked by 2 users. There is but one difference :

- The first one wants to discuss solutions (*what can be done?*) about the problem and only uses[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). It is also answered *(but the answer tell to discuss the subject on an another site)*.
- The second one is a[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)that seeks to implement a particular change in order to solve the problem. This one doesn’t use[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)and isn’t answered at all.

Should the[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)post be closed whatever the situation is *(even if it‘s older and better worded than the one with [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion))* ?

Answer (score 8):

It really depends. Generally, no.

The [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) post likely contains discussion surrounding the problem, and possible solutions. The [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) post, contains the actual request for the solution to be implemented into the system. People at SE also monitor feature requests on a frequent basis, and closing as a duplicate will take the post off of their radar.

A good rule of thumb (for any post as well) is to ignore the tags and just look at the contents. Are their purposes the same? If yes, then close. Otherwise, let both posts thrive. :)

Comment: Your last paragraph is pretty much the sole answer. The tags are not really relevant, as a lot of people mis-tag things, and a lot of discussion tags get used because users just want to "discuss the idea" even though it really is a feature request. The feature request tag itself already implies that discussion will take place regarding the identified feature.

Comment: @animuson : yes but if the feature request question is closed, then nothing will be implemented for sure.

Comment: @user2284570 you seem to be wrong [about 1,244 times](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes+[status-completed] "closed and status-completed questions")

Comment: @gnat : and how much time in this search result, the feature got implemented whereas they were already an accepted answer telling to [refuse everything for changing anything](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8542/please-don-t-make-careers-programmers-only) ? I think the number is 0.